# How to retrieve input from textbox on button press tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The title says it all. I have looked about for fixes and tried implementation of them but it seems to not work on my code.

Also, what is the difference to `.pack()` when you declare the widget/variable or on the next line?

```
from tkinter import *
import addition

main = Tk()

width = 600
height = 600

c = Canvas(main, width=width, height=height)
c.pack()

submitbutton = Button(c, width=10, height=1, text='SUBMIT').pack()

textbox = Text(c, width=30, height=2).pack()
tboxlabel = Label(textbox, text='label').pack()

quitbutton = Button(c, width=10, height=1, text='QUIT', command=quit).pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code does not have any stuff related to getting input from textbox.  For line like `textbox = Text(...).pack()`, `textbox` is assigned the result of `pack()` (which is None), not `Text(...)`.  So `textbox` will be None instead of an instance of `Text()`.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the second part of your question first: The `pack()` method always returns `None`, so your code what assigning that value to all the widgets except the `Canvas`.

To get the text when the <kbd>Submit</kbd> is pressed you need to define a callback function and then pass its name as the `command=` keyword argument when you create the `Button`. In the code below this function has been named `submit()`.

To get text from a `Text` widget, you need to call its `get()` method and pass it two indices. To get *all* the text use `get("1.0", END)`. This is done in the function and the retrieved text is printed.

```
from tkinter import *


main = Tk()

width = 600
height = 600

def submit():  # Callback function for SUBMIT Button
    text = textbox.get("1.0", END)  # For line 1, col 0 to end.
    print(f'{text=!r}')

c = Canvas(main, width=width, height=height, highlightthickness=0)
c.pack()

submitbutton = Button(c, width=10, height=1, text='SUBMIT', command=submit)
submitbutton.pack()

textbox = Text(c, width=30, height=2)
textbox.pack()

tboxlabel = Label(c, text='label')
tboxlabel.pack()

quitbutton = Button(c, width=10, height=1, text='QUIT', command=quit)
quitbutton.pack()

mainloop()
```

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like running on my system. When the <kbd>Submit</kbd> is clicked, it will retrieve the contents of the `Text` widget and print it out.

[image: screenshot of script running]

Comment: Normally `pack() / grid() / place()` is not used to put widgets into `Canvas`.  Also `c.create_window(100, 100, window=tboxlabel)` will be override by `tboxlabel.pack()`.

Comment: @acw1668: Agree the coordinates don't matter, however without the `tboxlabel.pack()` ,the `Label` is invisible.

Comment: It is not invisible, it is put in the upper left corner of the window (only bottom right part is visible).  If you use `anchor="nw"` in `.create_window(...)`, you will see the whole label.

Comment: @acw1668: A-ha, now I get it. Thanks for the clarification. However the point's now moot since I've revised my answer again and it is no longer using the `Canvas.create_window()` function (and just calls `pack()` like the OP does with the other widgets). I didn't know a `Canvas` could more-or-less be used just like a `Frame` — at least not to the degree it is being done here.

Comment: Yes you can use a `Canvas` like a container, but using `pack / place / grid` will not make the widgets to be scrollable (i.e. their position will not be changed if the canvas is being scrolled).  Also they are not included in the calculation of `scrollregion`

Comment: @acw1668: Given that, it seems relatively pointless to use a `Canvas` in conjunction with one those layout manager methods and the only things on it are going to be regular tkinter widgets (i.e. as opposed to other `Canvas`-only items like lines, ovals, polygons, etc. — or widgets inside "window" items).